# postgis SRTM3 different raster scale in same column

Tags: postgis, srtm, postgis-raster, hgt

SRTM3 elevation data are stored in HGT files each containing 1201x1201 values. I want to store this information in a `PostGIS raster` column with a single band.

To optimize my queries, I wanted to split these files in a smaller set. For example 50x50 (and some with 50x51 and 51x50 for the edge values).

When I ran the `raster2pgsql` command, it has generated a table with this constraint :

```
enforce_same_alignment_rast" CHECK (st_samealignment(rast, '010000000...'::raster))
```

It seems that it will fail the check if I split with my previous scheme. But 1201 is a prime number ...

So my question is this : is it possible to store different raster scale in the same raster column ? And if yes, will it have any negative impact ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the `St_SameAlignement` function.

As the doc says :

> ST_SameAlignment — Returns true if rasters have same skew, scale,
>   spatial ref, and offset (pixels can be put on same grid without
>   cutting into pixels) and false if they don't with notice detailing
>   issue.

So the `width` and `height` of a raster don't have any impact. Only the `skew` (rotation), `scale` (the size of a square inside the raster), `spatial ref` (the spatial reference system SRID) and `offset`.